# FPU precision not behaving differently?

Tags: gcc, rounding, precision, fpu

I found some code here (http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_70.html) which should demonstrate the difference between standard and double FPU precision. However, if I compile the code in both ways (either with DOUBLE defined or not), I get the same results. What I actually want to do is to get a good example which demonstrates the differences, but I didn't find even one working example yet.
Can anyone explain why this demonstration isn't working?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void 
set_fpu (unsigned int mode)
{
  asm ("fldcw %0" : : "m" (*&mode));
}

int
main (void)
{
  double a = 3.0, b = 7.0, c;
#ifdef DOUBLE
  set_fpu (0x27F);  /* use double-precision rounding */
#endif
  c = a / b;

  if (c == a / b) {
    printf ("comparison succeeds\n");
  } else {
    printf ("unexpected result\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
philipp@wurstbrot:/tmp> g++ test3.cpp -o test3.out
philipp@wurstbrot:/tmp> ./test3.out
comparison succeeds
philipp@wurstbrot:/tmp> g++ test3.cpp -DDOUBLE -o test3.out
philipp@wurstbrot:/tmp> ./test3.out
comparison succeeds
```

Comment: Perhaps your compiler has chosen to use the SSE units, rather than the FPU?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This would make sense, but how can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: @user3527289 Why can't you just demonstrate the difference between `double` and `float` with `c == (double)((float)a / (float)b)` instead of meddling with the FPU flags?

Comment: This is Intel/x87, right? I would think that the default precision would be extended double (80-bit), and that you're *decreasing* precision from that to standard double (64-bit), not increasing it from single to double.

Comment: Also if you don't use `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` then your code does not have to work (and even if you use it, the compiler may not support it).